# Should we continue weekly topics?

Tags: discussion

I think the question is pretty self explanatory.  I would like to know if the community is finding the weekly topics worthwhile.

Comment: Well I think it is a nice source of inspiration as well as covering all questions on a given topic. So YES

Answer (score 4):

I'm quite new to spotting the weekly topic posts (I know, I know, I just missed 'em okay?) but I think they are a great idea, even if they only spark a handful of extra questions that will help nudge our daily questions tally up a bit.